# Use of "study" and "studies" as noun

Tags: word-usage, nouns

> He left the service to pursue his studies.

> He left the service to pursue his study.

What is the key difference between these sentences?
Generally, *study* is used in the sense of learning, while *studies* is used in the sense of research. Sometimes it's confusing to understand it.

Is there any peculiar way to differentiate these two words, or can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: No,you can't use them interchangeably.

Comment: _Studies_ usually refers to academic work in general.  _Study_ (in this context) would imply a particular piece of work on a specific topic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally and idiomatically speaking, we use:

- He left the service to pursue his studies. [an idiom, i.e. at university]
- He left the service to pursue his study **of mathematics**.
- He excelled at biology while doing his studies. [i.e. at university]

The two above are not exactly the same. With "pursue his studies", we don't know exactly what he is studying.

It's just as simple as that.

Not be confused with:
We carried out several studies on frogs.
We carried out a study on the honeybee.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, as I'm sure you know, is that 'study' is singular while 'studies' is plural. As they mean or imply different things, they aren't strictly 'interchangeable' - there may be occasions when only one or the other fits. But I have heard both used to describe what is essentially the same thing. For example, I hear doctors say "*during my study...*" as well as "*during my studies...*".

'Studies' could imply multiple subjects were being studied, or that the study of a single subject involved multiple periods or multiple projects etc.

Equally, you could refer to someone's study of multiple subjects as 'study' in the singular, effectively grouping them together into a period of study if there is no need to differentiate.